# emacs el-get only runs one time, afterwards cannot be found

Tags: emacs, package, pymacs

I install el-get by typing this into my buffer, highlighting, and hitting `C-j`:

```
(url-retrieve
 "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el"
 (lambda (s)
   (goto-char (point-max))
   (eval-print-last-sexp)))
```

...according to [the installation documentation](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get).

I can then install things using `M-x el-get` commands.  Great so far.

However, when I close emacs and restart, `M-x el-get` cannot be found, nor can any of the packages I installed with it.  When I try to reinstall el-get in the method above, installation says the git package already exists:

`fatal: destination path 'el-get' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

I can delete the el-get directory in my `emacs.d/` folder and get back to the beginning, but can't seem to get el-get to stay installed beyond the first time.  What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Also---I'm only using el-get in the first place to be able to install auto-complete for using emacs for python development. If you have an easier or better easy-installation recipe for that, I'd appreciate that suggestion, too.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as Dmitry's points at the same heading, but perhaps you could suggest some improved wording for the readme file to the el-get maintainer if you think it needs clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Never used el-get myself, but...)

a) You should add the code from one of the examples in the `Basic Setup` section. It includes forms like `(add-to-list 'load-path ...)` and `(require 'el-get ...)`, which are more or less essential for loading Emacs packages.

b) You can just as well install `auto-complete` from [Marmalade](http://marmalade-repo.org/) or [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#installing). I think this is the recommended option if you're using Emacs 24. Add at least one of the repositories to `package-archives`, press `M-x list-packages RET`, look for `auto-complete`, press `i`, then `x`.